# Should libraries be synchronized with a repository (eg GitHub)

Tags: python-3.x, github, pycharm

PyCharm offers to synchronize imported packages (eg openpyxl) with repositories.

Is it good practice to synch these (even though they are imported standard packages)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no.

A virtual environment need not be replicated as the packages and their version can be listed with the pop freeze command into a text file called **requirements.txt** that should be shared.

Others can use this file to build up the libraries.